# Variable in bash script exported in function

Tags: bash, function

I have a function in a script, in which I would like to expand a variable. How do I do it?

eg:

set_function.sh:

```sh
function test_funct {some_binary --configfile="$1"/folder/; }
export -f test_funct
```

I would like it so that if I call:

./set_function.sh /some/path/here

the passed variable /some/path/here gets expanded so that if I then call

`test_funct --some-other-flag`

I don't get:

`some_binary --configfile=--some-other-flag/some_path/`

but rather

`some_binary --configfile=/some/path/here/folder/ --some-other-flag`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use variables, like this:

```
test_func() {
    some_binary --config $CONFIG_PATH/folder/ "$@"
}
```

and call it like

```
CONFIG_PATH=~/config1 test_func --verbose
export CONFIG_PATH=~/config2
test_func --quiet
```

Also note that you cannot export things upwards, i.e. you cannot call `set_function.sh` so that `test_func` be exported to the calling shell. You need `. set_function.sh` or equally `source set_function.sh` instead.